# could not find fixture:'packageName.className' when running fitnesse tests on remote machine

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, fixtures, fitnesse

I have developed a maven project in which I have created tests using fitnesse doFixture. The same is running fine on local machine. But when I deploy the same
on remote machine using:
**assembly:single install** (I have used maven assembly plugin to get an executable jar of my project along with all its dependencies)

On running any tests I get this error:
could not find fixture:'packageName.className'

Noteworthy, all the tests are running perfectly on local machine.

Can anyone help here? Is there something I am missing?

I read few articles saying to add !define TEST_SYSTEM {fit/slim} to my test page, but I didn't achieve any success by that also.

Comment: Have you setup the classpath correctly for the location you placed the jar with all its dependencies on the remote machine (I image it is different than locally)?

Comment: yes, that was the issue! thanks